# Finding the fibonacci number of large number

Tags: c++, dynamic, biginteger, fibonacci

I wrote the following program for finding the modulus of large Fibonacci's number. This can solve large numbers but fails to compute in cases like `fibo_dynamic(509618737,460201239,229176339)` where `a = 509618737`, `b = 460201239` and `N = 229176339`. Please help me to make this work.

```
long long  fibo_dynamic(long long  x,long long  y,long long  n, long long a[]){
    if(a[n]!=-1){
         return a[n];
    }else{
        if(n==0){
            a[n]=x;
            return x;
        }else if(n==1){
            a[n]=y;
            return y;
        }else {
            a[n]=fibo_dynamic(x,y,n-1,a)+fibo_dynamic(x,y,n-2,a);
            return a[n];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check the capacity or range of a `long long` to see if you overflow. You can expand the range by using `unsigned long long` if your compiler supports it.

Comment: Also review the stack capacity for your compiler or platform.  Each recursion stores data on the stack.

Comment: You need to verify that you have not exceeded the boundaries of the array. You need to pass the capacity of the array so you can make the comparisons.

Comment: Please be more specific than "fails to compute".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values will overflow because Fibonacci numbers increase very rapidly. Even for the original fibonacci series (where `f(0) = 0` and `f(1) = 1`), the value of `f(90)` is more than 20 digits long which cannot be stored in any primitive data type in C++. You should probably use modulus operator (since you mentioned it in your question) to keep values within range like this:

```
a[n] = (fibo_dynamic(x,y,n-1,a) + fibo_dynamic(x,y,n-2,a)) % MOD;
```

It is safe to `mod` the value at every stage because `mod` operator has the following rule:

```
if a = b + c, then:
a % n = ((b % n) + (c % n)) % n
```

Also, you have employed the recursive version to calculate fibonacci numbers (though you have memoized the results of smaller sub-problems). This means there will be lots of recursive calls which adds extra overhead. Better to employ an iterative version if possible.

Next, you are indexing the array with variable `n`. So, I am assuming that the size of array `a` is atleast `n`. The value of `n` that is mentioned in the question is very large. You probably cannot declare an array of such large size in a local machine (considering an integer to be of size `4 bytes`, the size of array `a` will be approximately `874 MB`).

Finally, the complexity of your program is `O(n)`. There is a technique to calculate n_th fibonacci number in `O(log(n))` time. It is "Solving Recurrence relations using Matrix Exponentiation." Fibonacci numbers follow the following linear recurrence relation:

```
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)   for n >= 2
```

Read [this](http://fusharblog.com/solving-linear-recurrence-for-programming-contest/) to understand the technique.